# PowerBI Dax Measure - Aggregate data using If and Multiple Conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having issues trying to aggregate data with multiple conditions in PowerBI Dax.

I have a PowerBI Dataset similar to the one below, which lists Call ID and multiple vehicle codes and am trying to create a measure that acts as a flag using the logic below:

- IF Vehicle_Code=H OR Vehicle_Code=HX are both present per CallID THEN Count the distinct CallID

Dataset:

[image: CallID 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]

Result:

[image]

Any help or advise would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So a given *CALLID* can only ever have a maximum of one instance of each of "H" and "HX", no more? If so, the following **measure** should work: `=INT(COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table','Table'[VEHICLE_CODE]IN{"H","HX"}))=2)`

Comment: Yes, its essentially just to check that the combination exists per Call ID. I have just realised I would then need to get the SUM of Call IDs flagged as 1? Could I incorporate that in the above dax code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
H HX Flag =
VAR H_List =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( TTable[CALLID] ), TTable[VEHICLE_CODE] = "H" )
VAR HX_List =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( TTable[CALLID] ), TTable[VEHICLE_CODE] = "HX" )
RETURN
    COUNTX ( INTERSECT ( H_List, HX_List ), [CALLID] )
```

If we test it:

[image: DFR]

Do not forget to click the down-pointing arrow on CALLID column and ensure that "show items with no data" is checked. See the below picture:

[image: DESR]

Comment: I have just tried this code and it works perfectly. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I am pleased to hear that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure:

```
H HX Flag = 
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[CALLID],
        "Flag",
            INT(
                COUNTROWS( FILTER( 'Table', 'Table'[VEHICLE_CODE] IN { "H", "HX" } ) ) = 2
            )
    )
RETURN
    IF( HASONEVALUE( 'Table'[CALLID] ), MINX( T1, [Flag] ), SUMX( T1, [Flag] ) )
```

The subtotal will give you the number of IDs flagged.